# Force image element to fill all available space

Tags: html, css

I have a container that contains 2 `p` elements and 1 `img` element.
I want the image to fill the whole available space.

So I tried using both `height: 100%` and `flex: 1` but it did not do the job.

Why?

```css
.x {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.y {
  flex: 1;
height: 100%;
border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <p>safdadsfds</p>
  <p>gadfgdfgdf<p>
  <img class="y" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: min-height:0 to the image

Comment: and correct your code because you are not correctly opening/closing your `p`